# Javascript using regex to replace whitespaces and other charaters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have this string `"Gem. Buitentemperatuur (etmaal)"`

And i would like to replace all whitespaces, capitals and special chars so that i end up with

```
"gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var yourStr = "Gem. Buitentemperatuur (etmaal)";
var newStr = yourStr.replace(/\s+/g, "_").replace(/\W+/g, "").toLowerCase();
//gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal
```

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is used to manipulate your string, a simple regular expression is passed to this and the value you want to replace it with

First we replace the Whitespace.

```
/  <- start the regex
\s <- match whitespace character
+  <- matches one or more times
/  <- end the regex.
```

And we replace this with your underscore `.replace(/\s+/g, "_")`

then find and match all non word characters.

```
/  <- start the regex
\W <- match all non word characters (everything but a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _)
+  <- matches one or more times
/  <- end the regex
```

This part looks like this `.replace(/\W+/g, "")`

the `g` after the closing `/` stands for global to look all along the string and not just for the first match.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7vwP/)

Answer (score 1):

```
"Gem. Buitentemperatuur (etmaal)".toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]+(?!$)/g, "_").replace(/^[^a-z]|[^a-z]$/, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
   return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
   return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
[^\w]+
```

And `.replace()` with `_`.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/nN9pX7

```
var str = "Gem. Buitentemperatuur (etmaal)";
str.replace(/\W+/g, "_").toLowerCase().replace(/(^_|_$)/, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s="Gem. Buitentemperatuur (etmaal)";
s.toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g, '_').replace(/\W+/g, '');
//=> "gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal"
```